# force 0 when blank with addcolumn summarize excel 2016 dax for more accurate averages

Tags: excel, dax, daxstudio

I have one table that has three columns: lisa, customers and activity_type. I want to count the number of rows by customer and activity type and then average them over all customers by activity types.
If this were a table in sql, I'd do

```
SELECT
    lisa,
    customer,
    activity_type,
    average(ct) 
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            lisa,
            customer,
            activity_type,
            CASE
                WHEN
                    s.ct IS NULL 
                THEN
                    0 
                ELSE
                    s.ct 
            END
            ct 
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    * 
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT DISTINCT
                            lisa,
                            customer 
                        FROM
                            TABLE
                    )
,
                    (
                        SELECT DISTINCT
                            activity_type
                    )
            )
            LEFT JOIN
                (
                    SELECT
                        lisa,
                        customer,
                        activity_type,
                        COUNT(*) ct 
                    FROM
                        TABLE 
                    GROUP BY
                        1,
                        2,
                        3
                )
                s 
    )
    s
```

But it's Dax, which is infinitely harder.  I tried:

```
=
AVERAGEX(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CROSSJOIN( VALUES( Query1[customer] ), VALUES( Query1[activity_type] ) ),
        "C", CALCULATE( COUNTA( Query1[engagio_activity_id] ) + 0 )
    ),
    IF( [C] = BLANK(), 0, [C] )
)
```

and

```
=
AVERAGEX(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE( Query1[lisa], Query1[activity_type] ),
        "C", CALCULATE( COUNTA( Query1[engagio_activity_id] ) + 0 )
    ),
    IF( [C] = BLANK(), 0, [C] )
)
```

But try as I might, I still get:
[image: failed pivot]
Where the blanks are not treated as 0 in the aggregate rows such as the "no" row in the picture above.  That roll up amount ignores the blanks when calculating the averages.  When I put the cross join into the dax studio, I forced the 0's

[image: 0s]
So it's a mystery to me where the 0s went.

Comment: the only thing that comes to mind is that the CROSSJOIN or the SUMMARIZE in the second one return no rows. You might try to add + 0 after the AVERAGEX()

Comment: It wasn't adding 0 after averagex()

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complicating

```
Average=
VAR totalCustomers = COUNTROWS(ALL(Query1[customer])) //this gives you total # of customers

RETURN 
  DIVIDE(COUNT(Query1[engagio_activity_id]) + 0, //the +0 forces the count to always return something
         totalCostumers)
```

Comment: This didn't work.  Instead it divided the number of rows by the number of customers regardless of whether there was a filter on the customer or not.  I'm trying to count a row whether it's there or not.

Comment: Oh, but this worked: divide(countrows(query1),CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT([customer]),all(Query1[activity_type])))